# How the function onhidden works in bootstrap and what it does specifically

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

Please help me understand how onhidden function work. I read in https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/ about it, but did not understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are the events... 
in simple words..

onhidden event will be fired when your modal will be gone off the screen.

Onhide event will be fired when modal hide action is done but before closing the dailog.

Comment: Thank you very much. This simple answer helped me.

Comment: glad to help :)